# How to grab dynamic date in SendGrid's Dynamic templates?

Tags: date, dynamic, sendgrid, email-templates

How do I get the current year for the Copyright © {{YEAR}} in a SendGrid Dynamic Templates WITHOUT test data?

I'm looking for something like `{{ formateDate new Date YYYY }}` since we want the year to update automatically so we can't rely on test data if that is possible?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this please?

Comment: I just messaged with SendGrid support. It doesn't seem like this is currently possible . Or at least the rep that I spoke to didn't know how to do it.

Comment: I was hoping that this is something which could be set like this `{{ formatDate "" "YYYY" }}`, I've raised a ticket with sendgrid. I guess until that becomes available that I'll need the value sent with the data payload posted to the template.